# How to install brain.js on Mac?

Tags: javascript, macos

I need help with downloading brain.js in to VS Code. I have looked on YouTube and Stack Overflow for answers, nevertheless I could not find any solution. I hope so one can describe me what to do.

Comment: You need to use node.js. Can you be a little more descriptive?

Comment: Related: [brain.js - Installation and Usage](https://github.com/brainjs/brain.js#Installation-and-Usage). System dependencies for Max OS X are listed as Python 2.7 and XCode.

Comment: I found the solution. I downloaded node and it worked. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt in the folder with the program and type

```
npm install --save brain.js
```

In the node.js program, put

```
const brain = require("brain.js");
```

If that doesnt work, go to the [website](https://brain.js.org/) and you might find something there, or i found this good video. [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVMHhtTqUxc)